# svg issue : xlink:href not working on ios with cordova and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, svg, xlink

I got a strange issue with svg and ios. I'm using angularjs and cordova.

I include an external svg in an angular app, and display it in my view this way :

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 640 550">
    <use xlink:href="#mysvg"></use>
</svg>
```

In my external svg, I got several g elements with links inside :

```
<a xlink:href="/path/to/page"></a>
```

This works fine on android but not on ios when I export the webview with cordova. It works on my iphone simulator...

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the xlink namespace to your SVG.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 640 550" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use xlink:href="#mysvg"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks for your answer. I've try your solution, but it still doesn't work. I keep working on it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just succeed with adding the xlink and namespace and put the links inside the svg with the use tag, not in the external svg. I had an other issue with the markup, apparently you have to close every tags otherwise each other tag will be wrapped in the first one, which breaks your layout ordering. For instance `<path />` doesn't work and `<path></path>` works fine.

Finally, I got something like this :

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 640 550" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use xlink:href="#mysvg"></use>
    <a xlink:href="/path/to/page">
        <path></path>
        <rect></rect>
        <text></text>
    </a>
</svg>
```